# performance testing tools for deskop application

Tags: test-automation-framework, performance, performance-testing, desktop-application

I am searching for an open source tool to record the functionalities of a desktop application functionalities like starting and ending time of each operation like load report rendering and maintain the log of every single action as well.

Any recommendation for desktop applications?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test application itself - the [profiling tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) for the programming language the application is written in is the best choice.

Alternatively you can use "normal" desktop automation tool like [Appium](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/) or [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

In case you want to simulate hundreds/thousands of applications concurrently accessing backend/database - you need to find a tool which supports [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols)(s) used for this communication, see [How to Do Desktop Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing) article for more information

Answer (score 0):

While working in a [software testing company](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company), I have experienced such requirements i.e. doing performance testing using an open-source tool. Apache JMeter is one of the best tools available in the market and high-level details are mentioned below -

"JMeter comes with the HTTP(S) Proxy Server, which can capture the requests between the web browser or mobile device and the backend and convert them into HTTP Request samplers."

So, if the desktop application you need to test uses HTTP or HTTPS protocols for communicating with the backend server, you should be able to record the requests with JMeter and replay them with an increased number of virtual users

Therefore you can use JMeter for load testing of almost any desktop application which communicates with the backend over HTTP.

Answer (score -1):

I have a non-answer that maybe should be a comment, but nevertheless-

Have a built in logging and monitoring system measuring those actions, preferably one with a level that you can control so i is not too "noisy" when used in production. This will allow you to test what you need but also test in production and identify problems before they become a real problem.
If you properly build the infrastructure then it becomes a no-brainer for the developers to sprinkle those measurements wherever needed.